# Exploding strings to words and copying to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id | name
1    foo bar something
2    something else
```

And I want to create another table based on it, containing single words with the foreign id matching its occurance in a string, like:

```
f_id | word
1      foo
1      bar
1      something
2      something
2      else
```

The thing is that the first table contains a couple of millions records. And I want this operation to be as fast as possible, because in the meantime there will be other tasks performed on the database.

I want to do this once a day.

What's the best way to do this?

---

I've been thinking about the simplest method, doing this with one SQL:

```
INSERT INTO table_output (f_id, word)
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.name, ' ', 3)
FROM table t;
```

But it could be quite slow, and I don't know how to write the proper SQL to do this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the best way to do this?

As always it depends. There is no one ultimate answer and you should prepare dev environment and do performance tests first.

One solution is to use tally table for multiple split:

```
SELECT id AS f_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.name, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) AS word
FROM mytable t 
CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.name, ' ', '')))
ORDER BY id, n
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bac8/4/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═══════════╗
║f_id ║   word    ║
╠═════╬═══════════╣
║  1  ║ foo       ║
║  1  ║ bar       ║
║  1  ║ something ║
║  2  ║ something ║
║  2  ║ else      ║
╚═════╩═══════════╝
```

You can also consider using external tools to do it. Read data from DB, process in application and save back to DB.

**EDIT:**

Exclude words that are less than 3 characters:

```
WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.name, ' ', '')))
  AND LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.name, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1)) > 2
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f9d9f/2/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more thing - how could I fetch only words that have more than 2 letters?

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP script for this.

like below

```
$offset = 0
do{
    $sql = "Select * from table1 limit 100, $offset
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $wordArr = explode(' ',$row['word']);
            insertRecordIntoOtherTable($row[id],$wordArr);
        }
    }
} while ($conditionToBreak);
```

Comment: Pulling a few million rows to the application layer when the result can be achieved within the DB is definitely not "the best way to do this".